# How to remove or disable language preferences key from iPad keyboard for specific text field

Tags: ios, ipad

[image: Needs to remove the key shown in keyboard or if it can be disable][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77fpb.png)

Needs to remove or disable key from iPad keyboard for specific text field, shown in the image

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Leave that key alone and filter out invalid input with `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Comment: How? please detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a specific button from keyboard unless you create a custom keyboard. But, there are different kinds of keyboard defined already. What you can do is  manage the keyboard behaviour.

**[yourTextField setKeyboardType: [UIKeyboardType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)]**;

Answer (score 2):

set in storyboard

[image]

or manually
[textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable];

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a key can be removed form key pad, how ever you can add an overlay at the same place over that image.

Comment: This post describes about adding custom key over keyboard you can add a button without any actions http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-to-custimize-a-keyboard.html

Comment: Except for one little problem - how do you know where that key appears? It may not even be there for some users. And it is not always in the exact same place depending on the current keyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy: If the keypad is launched within your app then you have the control over setting keyboard type. As far as location is concerned exact coordinates will be needed for different orientations. Never tried this solution my self but cant think of other solution at present.

Comment: If Apple figures out that the key is covered i.e. disabled they will most likely reject the app.